# Кол-во вхождений определённого символа в тексте, общее кол-во символов, кол-во слов в тексте

Tags: java, массивы, строки, файлы

Нужно написать программу, которая считает кол-во слов, символов(без учёта пробелов) и встречаемость какой-либо буквы в тексте "Война и мир", который дан в формате .txt.
      https://yadi.sk/i/BeKdtZnQ3TXmMs
    Не откажусь от любых советов по реализации программы.

Comment: Тут три задачи: лучше решать их по одной.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Считываешь в 1 огромную строку весь текст, также создаёшь 32 счётчика для каждой из букв(по умолчанию инициализируешь их нулями), циклом проходишься по строке и плюсуешь счётчики в случае совпадения(в случае пробела просто переходишь к след симовлу). Для слов создай отдельный счётчик, в который будешь инкрементить при обнаружении пробела

Answer (score 0):

Самый простой вариант

```
 int getNumberOfTheWorld(String source, String word) {
   String[] resArr = source.split(word);
   return resArr.length - 1;
   }
```

Comment: Думаю будет лучше написать что именно делает этот код и почему он работает.

Answer (score 0):

Можно сделать с помощью регулярных выражений

```
//Возвращает количество слов на латинице или кириллице
int numberOfWord(String text) {
        Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile("[A-Za-zА-Яа-я]+");
        Matcher matcher = pattern.matcher(text);
        int words = 0;
        while(matcher.find()) words++;
        return words;
    }

//Возвращает количество букв
int numberOfChar(String text, char searchChar) {
        Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile(Character.toString(searchChar));
        Matcher matcher = pattern.matcher(text);
        int chars = 0;
        while(matcher.find()) chars++;
        return chars;
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

1. Заводите счетчики:

   - количество слов
   - количество символов
   - количество каждого отдельного символа: `Map: Character->Long` (на основе него можно и общее количество символов посчитать)
2. Считывайте содержимое файла в строку
3. Итерируйтесь посимвольно (исключая спецсимволы):

   - на каждом символе увеличивайте счетчик общего количества символов и количества данного символа
   - на каждом пробеле, запятой, точке и т.п. увеличивайте счетчик слов

Упрощенный вариант реализации (без считывания из файла и различных проверок граничных ситуаций):

```
String text = "[1] Ну, здравствуйте, здравствуйте. Je vois que je vous fais peur,[2] садитесь и рассказывайте.\n"
        + "\n"
        + "Так говорила в июле 1805 года известная Анна Павловна Шерер, фрейлина и приближенная императрицы Марии Феодоровны, ";
AtomicLong totalCharCount = new AtomicLong();
AtomicLong wordCount = new AtomicLong();
AtomicInteger currentWordSize = new AtomicInteger(); //чтобы не учитывать пустые слова (например при "...")
Map<Character, Long> charsCount = new TreeMap<>(); //TreeMap - для сортировки символов

text.chars().forEach(ch -> {
    if (ch == '\n' || ch == '\r') {
        return;
    }
    if (ch == ' ' || ch == ',' || ch == '.' || ch == '?' || ch == '!') {
        if (currentWordSize.get() > 0) {
            wordCount.incrementAndGet();
            currentWordSize.set(0);
        }
    } else {
        totalCharCount.incrementAndGet();
        currentWordSize.incrementAndGet();
        Character character = (char) ch;
        charsCount.put(character, charsCount.getOrDefault(character, 0L) + 1);
    }
});
System.out.println("totalCharCount: " + totalCharCount);
// либо
// System.out.println("totalCharCount: " + charsCount.values().stream().mapToLong(Long::valueOf).sum());
System.out.println("words: " + wordCount);
System.out.println("chars:");
charsCount.forEach((k,v) -> System.out.format("'%s': %s\n", k, v));
```

Результат:

> ```
> totalCharCount: 174
> words: 31
> chars:
> '0': 1  
> '1': 2  
> '2': 1  
> '5': 1  
> '8': 1  
> 'J': 1  
> '[': 2  
> ']': 2  
> 'a': 1  
> 'e': 4  
> ...
> ```

Answer (score 0):

<sub>Время выполнения: `~227` миллисекунд.</sub>

---

Зачитал книгу по ссылке, там первые два тома только с примечаниями. Посчитал количество русских букв без учёта регистра. Алгоритм получился такой:

```java
FileReader reader = new FileReader("Vojna_i_Mir_Tolstoy_full_text.txt");

List<char[]> characters = new ArrayList<>();

char[] buf = new char[256];
while (reader.read(buf) > 0) {
    characters.add(buf);
    buf = new char[256];
}
```

```java
characters.stream().map(String::valueOf)
        // обходим все символы
        .flatMapToInt(String::codePoints)
        // отбираем только русские буквы
        .filter(ch -> ch >= 'а' && ch <= 'я' || ch == 'ё'
                || ch >= 'А' && ch <= 'Я' || ch == 'Ё')
        .boxed()
        // считаем количество букв
        .collect(Collectors.groupingBy(
                // без учета регистра
                ch -> Character.toLowerCase((char) ch.intValue()),
                Collectors.counting()))
        .entrySet().stream()
        // сортировка по убыванию количества
        .sorted(Map.Entry.comparingByValue(Comparator.reverseOrder()))
        // вывод
        .forEach(e -> System.out.println(e.getKey() + "=" + e.getValue()));
```

Вывод:

```
о=126127
а=93743
е=90761
и=72776
н=72492
т=63866
с=58701
л=56262
в=50736
р=49129
к=38358
д=33971
м=33261
у=30934
п=28151
я=25185
г=22399
ь=22223
ы=21146
б=19642
з=19343
ч=15753
й=12787
ж=11563
ш=10821
х=9599
ю=7156
ц=3916
э=3387
щ=3187
ф=2126
ъ=507
ё=60
```